# Groupbox not responding to coded opacity and visibility instructions

Tags: wpf

I have a groupbox that has an initial opacity of 0 (zero) , i.e: hidden.

When a button is clicked, an animation kicks off which sets the opacity from 0 -> 100 through 1 keyframe over 2 seconds. All of this works.

The groupbox actually contains a form, once this is submitted, I want to hide the groupbox.

Using code:

```
CampaignName.Text = ""; //works
CampaignFromEmail.Text = ""; //works
TemplatesCombo.ItemsSource = null; //works
TemplatesCombo.Items.Clear(); //works
GBCreateCampaign.Opacity = 0; // no effect
GBCreateCampaign.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden; //no effect
```

This in my opinion should work. Ok it won't have a fade out effect, but the point is the groupbox (GBCreateCampaign) is still very much visible on the screen with full opacity after this call.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An animation in WPF keeps on 'going' by default. So when you try to change the property in code (or any other way) it will be overruled or negated by the animation.

You'll need to either:

- Set the animation's FillBehavior property to Stop - so it stops setting the property to the `To` value of the animation after the animation has completed.

or

- Remove the entire Storyboard - note that all animations in the storyboard will be removed

or

- Remove the animation from the individual property.

[Source: MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970493.aspx)

Comment: Very interesting. So this "keeps on going" consumes a boat load of resources and memory?

Comment: That depends on the amount of animations in the UI. A single animation should not be that expensive, especially when the value does not change any more.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

Seems this issue causes a great deal of confusion.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970493.aspx